# fabric js: Polygon perPixelTargetFind

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm creating a Polygon with fabric.js and set its value "perPixelTargetFind" true.

When you click, for example, on the right top end (not inside the polygon, inside its bounding box), the polygon gets selcected, although "perPixelTargetFind" is set ( I though with this value it is only possible to select an object by directly clicking on it).
The polygon should only be selected, if you click directly on it, is this possible?

Here is a link to the issue on jsfiddle: [Polygon perPixelTargetFind](https://jsfiddle.net/5t4mfu7r/1/)

And here is my code so far:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';
document.getElementById("canvas").tabIndex = 1000;

var pol = new fabric.Polygon([
  {x: 200, y: 0},
  {x: 250, y: 50},
  {x: 250, y: 100},
  {x: 150, y: 100},
  {x: 150, y: 50} ], {
    left: 250,
    top: 150,
    fill: 'green',
    perPixelTargetFind: true
  }
);

canvas.add(pol);
```

thank you for your help! :)

Comment: uh yes it should not be selected. Would you be so nice to open an issue on the official issue tracker?

Comment: thanks for you reply, but are you sure its a real "bug"? i asked this question on google too, there they said, that the polygon is selected as soon as there is no object "under" it.. ?

Comment: is a bug because if it is transparent there it should not be selected.